# Dynamically changing a function __name__ throws AttributeError: 'method' object has no attribute '__name__'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to write a class that will catch any generic function call, then try some operations with it.

As an example, I try to use the answer to a similar question from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33133572/3024930).

However, it throws a `AttributeError: 'method' object has no attribute '__name__'` error when I try to change the method's name by assigning the `__name__` attribute.

The code I am using, adapted from the [example above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33133572/3024930) is:

```
class A():
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 1 # set some attribute

    def __getattr__(self,attr):
        return self.__get_global_handler(attr)

    def __get_global_handler(self, name):
        # Do anything that you need to do before simulating the method call
        handler = self.__global_handler
        handler.__name__ = name # Change the method's name
        return handler

    def __global_handler(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Do something with these arguments
        print("I am an imaginary method with name %s" % self.__global_handler.__name__)
        print("My arguments are: " + str(args))
        print("My keyword arguments are: " + str(kwargs))

    def real_method(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("I am a method that you actually defined")
        print("My name is %s" % self.real_method.__name__)
        print("My arguments are: " + str(args))
        print("My keyword arguments are: " + str(kwargs))
```

It works fine if I comment the line that change the method's name (`handler.__name__ = name # Change the method's name`):

```
>>> a.imaginary_method
<bound method A.__global_handler of <__main__.A object at 0x00000150E64FC2B0>>

>>> a.imaginary_method(1, 2, x=3, y=4)
I am an imaginary method with name __global_handler
My arguments are: (1, 2)
My keyword arguments are: {'x': 3, 'y': 4}
```

However, if I uncomment the line (to force the name change), I get:

```
>>> a.imaginary_method
[...]
AttributeError: 'method' object has no attribute '__name__'
```

What I expected to get was something like:

```
>>> a.imaginary_method
<bound method A.imaginary_method of <__main__.A object at 0x00000150E64FC2B0>>

>>> a.imaginary_method(1, 2, x=3, y=4)
I am an imaginary method with name imaginary_method
My arguments are: (1, 2)
My keyword arguments are: {'x': 3, 'y': 4}
```

So, is there a way to change the method's name on the fly like that? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason why `handler.__name__ = name` doesn't work is because `handler` is a *bound method*, i.e. it's an object that encapsulates a reference to a function and the instance that'll take the value of `self`. You can confirm this by printing it out; it says "bound method":

```
>>> a.imaginary_method
<bound method A.__global_handler of <__main__.A object at 0x00000150E64FC2B0>>
```

You can access the underlying function through the `__func__` attribute and change its name:

```
def __get_global_handler(self, name):
    handler = self.__global_handler
    handler.__func__.__name__ = name # Change the method's name
    handler.__func__.__qualname__ = __class__.__qualname__ + '.' + name
    return handler
```

The problem with this approach, though, is that all "imaginary methods" actually refer to the very same `__global_handler` method. If you try to create two methods with different names, you'll see that they actually both have the same name (because they're the same method):

```
a = A()
foo = a.foo
bar = a.bar

print(foo)  # <bound method A.bar of <__main__.A object at 0x00000212AFCC7198>>
print(bar)  # <bound method A.bar of <__main__.A object at 0x00000212AFCC7198>>
```

So, a better solution is to create a new function each time:

```
class MethodFactory:
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        def func(*args, **kwargs):
            print("I am an imaginary method with name", name)
            print("My arguments are:", args)
            print("My keyword arguments are:", kwargs)

        func.__name__ = name
        func.__qualname__ = __class__.__qualname__ + '.' + name
        return func

a = MethodFactory()
foo = a.foo
bar = a.bar
print(foo)  # <function MethodFactory.foo at 0x00000238BDADC268>
print(bar)  # <function MethodFactory.bar at 0x00000238BF8AB730>
```

As you can see, a side effect of this implementation is that `foo` and `bar` are regular functions instead of bound methods. If, for some reason, you have to return bound methods, you can manually convert the function to a bound method by calling its [`__get__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__get__) method:

```
class MethodFactory:
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        def func(self, *args, **kwargs):
            print("I am an imaginary method with name", name)
            print("My arguments are:", args)
            print("My keyword arguments are:", kwargs)

        func.__name__ = name
        func.__qualname__ = __class__.__qualname__ + '.' + name
        return func.__get__(self, type(self))

a = MethodFactory()
foo = a.foo
bar = a.bar
print(foo)  # <bound method MethodFactory.foo of <__main__.MethodFactory object at 0x00000137BF0C29E8>>
print(bar)  # <bound method MethodFactory.bar of <__main__.MethodFactory object at 0x00000137BF0C29E8>>
```